# How to have live connection "to" g-sheet" from DWH?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, live-streaming

I am interested to have live connection between Snowflake [DWH] and g-sheet.
I already tried couple of solutions but non of them was working properly.
The best solution that I currently have is to use Trevor app on Heroku and then write queries there. Then create a live connection between Trevor and g-sheet.
There are some downsides to this approach - one of them is that even if you do not open the g-sheet, Trevor is running the query in Snowflake every 10 min [ or 60 mins].

From Data Perspective I know that having live connection to g-sheet from "Modelled data" in DWH is not correct but at the current stage of my company, for some of the business owner we need to have something like this.

Do you know any tool OR have any experience with handling similar situations?

Answer (score -1):

There are solutions available using python and the jdbc driver. Just google "google sheets jdbc snowflake"